# iPhone app localization with custom system, how to make it appear on iTunes?

Tags: iphone, localization, itunes

My applicaton was ported from a PC version that used a custom localization system, using hardcode strings and some language rules to automatically translate text.
Everything works, it automatically detects the user language and displays the text using the correct translated strings. Right now it supports French, Spanish and German.
However I want that the supported languages to appear in iTunes, instead of just displaying 'English'.
How does iTunes find what language an app supports?
Is there any configuration file that I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the supported languages under the Localizations (CFBundleLocalizations) key in your Info.plist.